# MySQL Array is returning nothing/1's

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a messageboard, and I'm just starting it, working on the login function right now. I have an issue though. Whenever I try to fetch data it returns either nothing, or a "1". I don't know whats going on given that I'm new to integrating mySQL with PHP. If you can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

```
    $query = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'
");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $dbID = $row['id'];
    $dbUser = $row['username'];
    $dbPass = $row['password'];
}

if ($dbUser = $username && $dbPass = $password) {
    //if user and pass match do stuff
    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbUser;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $dbID;
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    header("Location: messageboard.php");
}
else {
    //if user and pass dont match do stuff
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "Your username and password do not match";
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

All of that code returns - 
ID: 
Username: 1
IP: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: `if ($dbUser = $username && $dbPass = $password) {` - you should be using `==` for loose comparisons. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: Also, your `while` loop is going through the whole result set, rather than just the one row you want. So unless the user is the last one, they won't be able to log in.

Comment: My query that the fetch is running is only where the username equals the username determined by the form.

Comment: @GeorgeColeman - mea culpa, so it is. That doesn't invalidate the issue with `=` and `==`, though

Comment: Yea i fixed that and its working now, running through all of the checks though. Hopefully it will work properly. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but it works perfectly now. Who would of known, just the == holding me back. Thanks andrew. And Jason I'll look into those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as stated by andrewsi: `$dbUser = $username && $dbPass = $password` should use `==` to compare values.

Second: Doing it like THIS is very vulnerable.

First, it seems like you have stored the password in "plaintext", so you could use the direct comparision. DON'T do so. Store a (salted, or peppered) Hash, and compare the user-input to that hash!

Second: You are using a WHILE-Loop (`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){`) to set the user data. That's not required, as one user-name should have exactly ONE set of data.

Third: You use `$username` in your query. Your example does not contain the generation of `$username`, but from what I see in your sourcecode, it most likely might look like `$username = $_POST["username"]`.

So, at this point, One might be able to modify the entered Username in a way to receive a valid login, EVEN if it is not. (SQL-Injection).

Escape User-Input (using `MySQL_real_escape_string()` BEFORE passing it to a SQL-Query.